Convex function with $f(0)=0$
Let $f:\mathbf{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be a convex function.
The book I'm reading is showing that $f$ must be continuous. The proof is done in steps, and in one of those steps it argues that if $f$ is convex, $f(0)=0$ and $f\not\equiv0$ in $B$ then $sup\{f(x),x \in B\} \neq 0$, where $B=\{x \in \mathbf{R}^n, ||x||_1 \leq 1 \}$ (obviously it's at least $\geq 0$), but the book does not prove it.
How could I show this? Thank you.

As $f\not\equiv 0$, there exists some $x_1\in B$ (which must be non-zero as $f(0)=0$) such that $f(x_1)\neq0$. If $f(x_1)>0$ we are finished.
Otherwise, $f(x_1)< 0$. If we had that $f(-x_1)\leq0$ then $$f\left(\frac{1}{2}x_1+\frac{1}{2}(-x_1)\right)=f(0)=0\not\leq \frac{1}{2}f(x_1)+\frac{1}{2}f(-x_1)$$
contradicting the convexity of $f$. Thus, $f(-x_1)>0$ and the mentioned supremum is strictly positive, as desired.

Very good. Thank you!
